# How to manage this long fraction in latex

Tags: math-mode, formatting, fractions

```
$$  \pi(\tau|x)= \frac{ B(S_{\tau}+a,b) \,_2F_1(S_{\tau}+\tau r, S_{\tau}+a, S_{\tau}+a+b; -\frac{1}{r})}
{\sum_{\tau=1}^{n} B(S_{\tau}+a,b) \,_2F_1(S_{\tau}+\tau r, S_{\tau}+a, S_{\tau}+a+b; -\frac{1}{r})}  $$

\begin{equation}
  \times \frac{B(S_{n-\tau}+a_1,b_1) \,_2F_1(S_{n-\tau}+(n-\tau) r, S_{n-\tau}+a_1, S_{n-\tau}+a_1+b_1;  -\frac{1}{r}) }{B(S_{n-\tau}+a_1,b_1) \,_2F_1(S_{n-\tau}+(n-\tau) r, S_{n-\tau}+a_1, S_{n-\tau}+a_1+b_1;  -\frac{1}{r})}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Even if the title gives hint on what your asking, being a bit more explicit would help us help you!

Answer (score 2):

I assume, that you wish to merge both equation in one, two line equation. In this the use of package `amsmath` or `mathtools` (improved version of `amsmath`) and their math environments like `multline`, `align` etc are handy:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{showframe}% for show page layout, in real use had to be omitted
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}  
\pi(\tau|x) = 
    \frac{B(S_{\tau}+a,b)_2 F_1(S_{\tau}+\tau r, S_{\tau}+a, S_{\tau}+a+b; -\frac{1}{r})}
          {\sum\limits_{\tau=1}^{n} B(S_{\tau}+a,b)_2 
                             F_1(S_{\tau}+\tau r, S_{\tau}+a, S_{\tau}+a+b; -\frac{1}{r})} 
          \times\\
    \frac{B(S_{n-\tau}+a_1,b_1)_2F_1(S_{n-\tau}+(n-\tau)r, S_{n-\tau}+a_1, S_{n-\tau}+a_1+b_1;  -\frac{1}{r}) }
        {B(S_{n-\tau}+a_1,b_1)_2F_1(S_{n-\tau}+(n-\tau)r, S_{n-\tau}+a_1, S_{n-\tau}+a_1+b_1;  -\frac{1}{r})}
\end{multline}
or
\begin{equation}
\pi(\tau|x) =
    \frac{B(S_{\tau}+a,b)_2 F_1(S,\tau,r)}
          {\sum\limits_{\tau=1}^{n} B(S_{\tau}+a,b)_2 F_1(S,\tau,r)} \times
    \frac{B(S_{n-\tau}+a_1,b_1)_2F_1(S,n,\tau,r)}
         {B(S_{n-\tau}+a_1,b_1)_2F_1(S,n,\tau,r)}
\end{equation}
where
    \begin{align*}
F_1(S,\tau,r)   & = F_1(S_{\tau}+\tau r,      S_{\tau}+a,     S_{\tau}+a+b;       -\frac{1}{r})\\
F_1(S,n,\tau,r) & = F_1(S_{n-\tau}+(n-\tau)r, S_{n-\tau}+a_1, S_{n-\tau}+a_1+b_1; -\frac{1}{r})     
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Let mi noted, that second part of equation is equal 1 :) (or you have some error in it).